# Sympy: plot x,y equation as a curve without solve it

Tags: matplotlib, sympy

I got a equation: `f = x**3 + 2*x*y + y**2 - 9`, I just want direct plot it in x,y plane. But now what I'm doing is first `solve(f)`, then plot the solutions one by one like the graph below, I want to know if is there a way to **direct** plot a curve from such an equation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `plot_implicit`:

```
from sympy import symbols, plot_implicit
x, y = symbols('x, y')
f = x**3 + 2*x*y + y**2 - 9
plot_implicit(f, (x, -3, 3), (y, -5, 10))
```

[image: plot of implicitly defined curve]

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the most compact way to achieve what you want.

```
plot(*solve(f, y), (x, -3, 3))
```